# How to do dynamic vue routing correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I want to make dynamic routing for the site, which depends on the agreement change. I have the following path tree:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        redirect: "/home",
        component: DefaultLayout,
        meta: {
             requiresAuth: true,
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: "/home",
                name: "HomeView",
                component: HomeView,
            },
            {
                path: "/calendar",
                name: "CalendarView",
                component: CalendarView,
            },
            {
                path: "/notes",
                name: "NotesView",
                component: NotesView,
            },
            {
                path: "/settings",
                name: "SettingsView",
                component: SettingsView,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: "/terms-of-use",
        name: "TermsOfUseView",
        component: TermsOfUseView,
        meta: {
            isGuest: true,
        },
    },
    {
        path: "/agreement",
        redirect: "/offer",
        component: AgreementLayout,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/offer",
                name: "OfferView",
                component: OfferView,
            },
            {
                path: "/public",
                name: "PublicView",
                component: PublicView,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: "/auth",
        name: "AuthorizationView",
        component: AuthorizationView,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
        },
    },
    {
        path: "/plug",
        name: "PlugView",
        component: PlugView,
    },
];
```

At the same time, I am tracking (so far only) agreement.

```
const agreement = computed(() => store.state.agreement);
```

Also I have a hook

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !agreement.value) {
        next({ name: "TermsOfUseView" });
    } else if (
        agreement.value &&
        (!store.state.user.google_token || !store.state.user.apple_token)
    ) {
        next({ name: "AuthorizationView" });
    } else if (store.state.user.token && to.meta.isGuest) {
        next({ name: "HomeView" });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

On the TermsOfUse page, clicking on I agree changes the value of agreement. And after that an error occurs:

```
Detected a possibly infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/terms-of-use" to "/auth". Aborting to avoid a Stack Overflow.
```

What would be the best way to configure this routing, which will depend on dynamic values?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your route in an endless loop.
Use `(!store.state.user.google_token && !store.state.user.apple_token)` instead of `(!store.state.user.google_token || !store.state.user.apple_token)`.

Comment: I can have either a google token or an apple token